# I am using sailsjs, and i want to integrate winston-sentry with it. I am having hard luck in adding meta data to sentry. My code looks below :

Tags: sails.js, error-logging, sentry, winston

I am using sailsjs, and i want to integrate winston-sentry with it. I am having hard luck in adding meta data to sentry. My code looks below :

in config/log.js

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
                     new sentry({
                          level: 'error',
                          dsn: 'sentrydsn',
                          patchGlobal: true,
                          json: true,
                          globalTags: {
                            productVersion: "1.2"
                          }
                         })
                     ]
    });
module.exports.log = {

    custom  : logger

};
```

in the serverError.js

```
sails.log.error('Sending 500 ("Server Error") response', data, {
userInformation: {
         os: "linux",
         browser: "chrome",
       }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this part. Instead of using `winston-sentry` . I used raven middleware directly in `http.js`. Make sure to add the order correctly, for me the order was:

```
  order: [
        'startRequestTimer',
        'cookieParser',
        'session',
        'myRequestLogger',
        'bodyParser',
        'handleBodyParserError',
        'compress',
        'methodOverride',
        'poweredBy',
        '$custom',
        'router',
        'ravenRequestHandler',
        'ravenErrorHandler',
        'www',
        'favicon',
        '404',
        '500'
      ]
```